# Parsing data from XML using Ruby and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, parsing, xml

I have a method that parses XML into an array of hashes.

Here is the original XML:

```xml
<rowset name="skillqueue" key="queuePosition" columns="queuePosition,typeID,level,startSP,endSP,startTime,endTime">
  <row queuePosition="0" typeID="20495" level="3" startSP="2829" endSP="16000" startTime="2013-03-04 16:25:50" endTime="2013-03-05 01:02:20"/>
  <row queuePosition="1" typeID="19767" level="4" startSP="40000" endSP="226275" startTime="2013-03-05 01:02:20" endTime="2013-03-07 06:40:31"/>
</rowset>
```

Here is the final array of hashes:

```ruby
[{:queuePosition=>"0", :typeID=>"20495", :level=>"3", :startSP=>"2829", :endSP=>"16000", :startTime=>"2013-03-04 16:25:50", :endTime=>"2013-03-05 01:02:20"}, {:queuePosition=>"1", :typeID=>"19767", :level=>"4", :startSP=>"40000", :endSP=>"226275", :startTime=>"2013-03-05 01:02:20", :endTime=>"2013-03-07 06:40:31"}]
```

Here is the method, which uses [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) for parsing:

```ruby
def get_training_queue(xml_data)
  queue = []
  xml_data.xpath("//row").each do |skill_in_queue|
    skill = {}
    skill_in_queue.attributes.each do |details|
      skill[details[0].to_s.to_sym] = details[1].to_s
    end
    queue << skill
  end
  queue
end
```

This works great, but it feels a bit inelegant.

- I'm curious if there is a better way to create the hashes within the internal loop?
- I am calling `to_s` because I couldn't figure out a way to pull out just the key/value without doing so, and it 'feels' like I'm missing some more elegant way of doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by using `map` instead of `each` plus `<<`; creating an array and then adding to it isn't very Ruby-like.

Second, [`Node#attributes`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-attributes) is a hash already, so one way to go is to modify a duplicate of it, rather than "manually" copying each key/value to a new hash. Also, the keys are strings so `to_s.to_sym` can be replaced by just `to_sym`.

To do the hash-conversion, I've used the same `keys.each` approach as what Rails uses in its [`symbolize_keys!` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys-21).

```
def get_training_queue(xml_data)
  xml_data.xpath("//row").map do |row|
    skill = row.attributes.dup
    skill.keys.each do |key|
      skill[key.to_sym] = skill.delete(key).to_s
    end
    skill
  end
end
```

Here's a different, super-brief, approach that uses the `Hash[ [key, value] , ... ]` syntax

```
def get_training_queue(xml_data)
  xml_data.xpath("//row").map do |row|
    Hash[ row.attributes.map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, v.to_s] } ]
  end
end
```

Either one should give you the right result, though.

Comment: you can safely remove that `to_a` :-)

Comment: @tokland Good call. Wonder why I even put that in there... :P

Answer (score 4):

Notes:

- Use functional `Enumerable#map` instead of imperative pattern `obj = []` +  `Enumerable#each` + `Array#<<`.
- Use [Kernel#Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash) to build a hash from its pairs. Note that this method is very ugly and some prefer a more OOP approach, in that case check [Enumerable#mash](http://rdoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#graph-instance_method) from Facets.
- Use `nokogiri_node.text`.
- Arguments in blocks can be unpacked.

I'd write:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'facets'

def get_training_queue(xml_data)
  xml_data.xpath("//row").map do |skill_in_queue|
    skill_in_queue.attributes.mash do |name, attribute|
      [name.to_sym, attribute.text]
    end
  end
end
```

All those `each`s and in-place updates show that you think in imperative terms instead of functional, check [this wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming).

Comment: I had failed to get around to messing with facets up to this point - so interesting solution.  Both answers presented in this thread were helpful, but Flambino offered two helpful solutions so I'm going to go ahead and issue them the answer.  Upvote though :)

Comment: @Ecnalyr: no problem, the solutions are almost identical. Make sure you read a bit about FP though, great stuff!